# Cpp inheritance - Parent function, child variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a class with a function and a subclass. 
In the following code, I want to override the `int x` in a way that `d.getX()` return 40.

```
using std::cout, std::endl;

class Base {
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Base(int y) : y(y) {};
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    int x = 40;
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    Base d(10);
    cout << d.getX() << endl; // want to print 40
    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: This question shows a fundamental lack of understanding about how inheritance works.  I recommend taking a look at our [list of textbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you are not creating a `Derived` object, so your code to set the value of `x` to 40 is never called.  It might even get optimized out completely.

But even so, `Derived` is declaring its own `x` member that *shadows* the `x` member in `Base`, so `Base::x` is never being assigned a value.  You need to get rid of `Derived::x` and make `Derived` update `Base::x` instead.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Base {
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Base(int y) : y(y) {};
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int y) : Base(y) { x = 40; }  
};

int main() {
    Derived d(10);
    cout << d.getX() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/IAbJiP)